# Java enhanced for loop (for each loop) throws Exception

Tags: java, list, swing, foreach, collections

I was recommended to use a `List<JLabel> list = new ArrayList<class>` to collect and later remove a number of unspecific JLabel images from my `JPanel`

```
private List<JLabel> cardImages = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
```

```
public void addCardImage(BufferedImage img, boolean playerCard) {

        JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon icon;
        icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        imgLabel.setIcon(icon);
        cardImages.add(imgLabel);
        if (playerCard)
            pCardPanel.add(imgLabel);
        else
            dCardPanel.add(imgLabel);
        display.pack();

    }
```

```
private void removeCards() {
    for (JLabel imgLabel : cardImages) {
        remove(imgLabel);
        cardImages.remove(imgLabel);
    }
    display.pack();
}
```

This code gives me
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
```

In the line

```
for (JLabel imgLabel : cardImages) {
```

(I don't know if this matters but the Game is runnable and is running on a thread.)
I copied the code as given to me in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62333343/2180785) and I don't see the problem, any ideas?                        Thanks in advance.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806421/concurrentmodificationexception-when-adding-inside-a-foreach-loop-in-arraylist

Comment: I wouldn't remove the `JLabel`s in this particular case, I'd instead remove the icon inside them. (`label.setIcon(null)`) and set it back when you want to update it. Instead of removing the component itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
for (JLabel imgLabel : cardImages) {
    remove(imgLabel);
    cardImages.remove(imgLabel); // not allowed!
}
```

You cannot iterate over the elements from a collection and remove elements from it at the same time, that results in a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Do this instead:

```
for (JLabel imgLabel : cardImages) {
    remove(imgLabel);
}
cardImages.clear();
```